Helping Typescript understand the type of value held by ComputerRef
I have a variable called animal of type ComputedRef<Animal | undefined>, and I have a function useAnimal that expects an argument of type ComputedRef<Animal>.
How can I make it so that I just call the function useAnimal if the type held by the animal ComputedRef is of the type Animal?
I have tried this:
 if (animal.value) {
   useAnimal(animal) // Typescript still things animal is of type ComputedRef<Animal | undefined>
 }


so where is the function?

The contents of the function are irrelevant. The problem is with the type of argument its expecting. I don't even have access to modify the contents of the function.

where the declaration and setting of  animal happens my dude, thats pretty important peice. not your hook

Why is that important? I have a variable of a type, and a function that expects another type. That's all that matters, my dude.

looks like you got the explanation below. Type defined for animal vs the expected type in useAnimal.

This is potential XY problem.
A typeguard like if (animal.value) doesn't work for a generic, this requires to use a helper function:
function checkDefinedRef<T>(v: Ref<T>): v is Ref<NonNullable<T>>  {
  return unref(v) != null;
}

It would be more complicated to infer Ref, ComputedRef, etc types based on input type, but most times this wouldn't be needed.
Considering that useAnimal accepts a ref (Ref instead of ComputedRef for consistency), it would be:
if (checkDefinedRef(animal)) {
  useAnimal(animal);
}

This indicates the problem with potential use of a ref. Composables are accepting ref to reference a value in future, otherwise a value could be provided instead of a reference. That animal is Animal now doesn't guarantee it won't be undefined in future.
The solution is to make useAnimal accept values instead of refs in case it accesses a value immediately and future value of a ref doesn't matter:
function useAnimal(valueOrRef: MaybeRef<Animal>) {
  const value = unref(valueOrRef);
  ...

Or make useAnimal handle itself nullable ref values that may change with time, which is common for composables due to how they are used:
function useAnimal(valueRef: Ref<Animal | null | undefined>) {
  ...
  const value = unref(valueRef);
  if (value != null)
    ...

